# Line Expansion Submersible pump

Tags: pump

Is it possible to take a regular submersible pump with a garden hose-sized line, and introduce it into a larger diameter line so that I may pull larger material from the water source? I'm thinking of some kind of jet pump type hybrid?

Comment: In theory, yes (if it's a powerful pump). In reality, probably not, unless you're only hoping to get the larger bulk of water to move without a lot of force. An experiment would probably be the best test. Q: what's the application?

Answer (score 1):

Only if it's a Dirty Water Pump. But, it won't pump any more volume than it does now & a bigger hose won't mean anything if the hose's mount isn't replaced with something bigger too.

Comment: Agreed. If the OP wants to "pull larger material from the water source" and not have it clog, they need a [trash pump](http://www.powerequipmentdirect.com/stories/272-How-to-Pick-the-Perfect-Submersible-Water-Pump.html).